# What is the XPATH query to extract contents of a class from a div on a webpage in php?

Tags: php, xpath

I have written the following code but it just returns empty data :

```
enter code here 
$code="CS225";

$url="https://cs.illinois.edu/courses/profile/{$code}";
echo $url;
$html = file_get_contents($url); 

$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); 

    $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

    $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query("//div[@id='extCoursesDescription']");

    if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
        foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
            echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

the website that i am trying to scrape is : https://cs.illinois.edu/courses/profile/CS225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The course content seems to be loaded on the source by the page on loading.  But if you go through the source that is loaded you get to ...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ws.engr.illinois.edu/courses/item.asp?n=3&course=CS225'></script>
```

From this you can track through to the url `http://ws.engr.illinois.edu/courses/item.asp?n=3&course=CS225` and this gives you the actual content your after.  So rather than the original URL, use this new one and you should be able to extract the information from there.

Although this content is all wrapped in `document.write()`'s.

**Update:**

To remove the `document()` bits - a simple way is to just process the content...

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$html = str_replace(["document.write('","');"], "", $html);
$html = str_replace('\"', '"', $html);
```

Comment: So is there any special way to query the document writes ?

Comment: I am trying . $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//div[@id="\extCoursesDescription\"]'); but it still returns blank

Comment: I've added some processing to remove the extra bits, and it seems to get some content :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! this was so helpful.